# Variable from php to

Tags: javascript, php

I have problems with javascript which i don't know :(
I have a string message in database, and when i click the button executing the function
The javascript function is replacing messagebox with message + variable m
At least it should do this... I think this variable should be used in some other way but i have no idea how to do it

Here is PHP fragment:

```
 $m = $allmessages['message']; //<<<<<THIS IS STRING
    echo "<button class='my-button' onClick=\"openmsg($m)\">";
```

And here script:

```
 <script>
    function openmsg(m) {
        $(document).ready(function(){
        var m;
    document.getElementById("messagebox").innerHTML = "Message:" + m;
        });
    }
    </script>
```

Error says that variable is undefined

Comment: Why i always get minueses for my questions ...........

Comment: Maybe because of the crappy title? From php to what?

Comment: Oh i was sure i completed it :D

Answer (score 3):

Wrap the `$m` in quotes, since it's a string. Also, your function doesn't need a DOM ready function and no need to re-declare `m` within the function:

```
echo "<button class='my-button' onClick=\"openmsg('$m')\">";
```

And the JS:

```
function openmsg(m) {
    document.getElementById("messagebox").innerHTML = "Message: " + m;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your javascript your are setting m to nothing:

```
var m;
```

Your function should be:

```
<script>
    function openmsg(m) {
        document.getElementById("messagebox").innerHTML = "Message:" + m;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I thought that i always have to declare it, thanks